# I'm working on a binary search tree for my independent class and I can't figure out why this isn't returning the correct height

Tags: java

```
public int getHeight() {
    return heightFinder(root, 0);
}
```

This is the recursive method that actually figures out the height, it compares the count of one path to the count of another path and then should pick the higher count all the way up.

```
public int heightFinder(BTNode roo, int count) {
    if(roo == null) {
        return count--;
    }
    else
        return (heightFinder(roo.getLeft(), count++) > heightFinder(roo.getRight(), count++)) ?
                heightFinder(roo.getLeft(), count++) : heightFinder(roo.getRight(), count++);
}
```

Comment: practical question: why are you repeating yourself via a ternary, instead of putting the left and right heights in two `int` vars, then comparing those, instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just want to get it done then I'm gonna clean it up with stuff like that

Comment: Protip: don't write code you need to clean up later. Just write decent code up front for code that is as simple as this, and immediately remove a possible source of bugs because you might have had a typo in that duplicated code.

Comment: (hint: you're increasing `count` three times, inside of the correct number of times, thanks to copy paste, thus shooting yourself in the foot for the sake of "getting it done" instead of "doing it right")

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this code:

```
heightFinder(roo.getLeft(), count++) > heightFinder(roo.getRight(), count++)) ?
heightFinder(roo.getLeft(), count++) : heightFinder(roo.getRight(), count++)
```

For each `heightFinder` call you execute `count++` which will increment `count` and return the new value.

Assuming that `count` starts out as `0` (as it does on the first invocation) you'll pass `1` to the first `heightFinder` call, `2` to the second `heightFinder` call and `3` to the third `heightFinder` call.

Additionally you should really remember the values for the first 2 calls instead of re-executing the "winning" branch. Because otherwise you'll traverse the whole tree multiple times for no real benefit, but that one doesn't affect correctness, only performance.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that about "++" (gonna go clean it up now with the 2 vars)

Answer (score 2):

Either of these two variants are possible

```
/** Depth of current subtree. */
public int heightFinder(BTNode roo) {
    return roo == null
        ? 0
        : 1 + Math.max(heightFinder(roo.getLeft()), heightFinder(roo.getRight()));
}
```

You did pass a count:

```
/** 
 * Entire tree depth.
 * @param count length from root to current node.
 */
public int heightFinder(BTNode roo, int count) {
    return roo == null
        ? count
        : Math.max(heightFinder(roo.getLeft(), count + 1),
                   heightFinder(roo.getRight(), count + 1));
}
```

Doing `count++` will have total different effects than `count + 1` and that after the old value is used. It cannot be repeated for instance; would need to be stored in a `countPlus1`. Also you have 4 recursive calls, as you do not store the result of the recursive call.

Both variants have a different perspectives: the first says: what is the depth of left and right subtrees (without the depth of the node we are in), and the second keeps the depth till the current node.

As you need to compare the depths of left and right, so compare partial results,
not based on any depth till the current node, the first solution is more elegant.

Of course, Math.max is phantastic here.